# Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, getimagedata

So I've been working on a fun, online image effect program in javascript where the user enters a url to an image and hits 'enter', the image is drawn on the screen, and then the user can run some effects on it, such as g for greyscale, b for blur, etc.

My problem is that the console prints out either:

> Redirect at origin [origin] has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

or:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
>   cross-origin data.

I looked into many answers to this issue, and I added an extension to my chrome browser that enables cross-origin resource sharing, and my webpage runs fine (after a couple of reloads).

All the solutions I found require either enabling the cross-origin resource sharing option in chrome, or using some sort of php and ajax calls to enable this option. **Since I'm writing the code on jsbin, I'm looking specifically for a solution that can be done in pure javascript,** and I haven't been able to find any that work. If you have any ideas on something that could work, or the news that there is no possible solution, any response would be appreciated.

My code:

```
var background, context, image;
var docwidth, docheight;

image = new Image();
image.src = $('#image-src').val();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

docwidth = $(document).outerWidth(true);
docheight = $(document).outerHeight(true);

background = document.getElementById("background");
context = background.getContext("2d");

image.onload = function() {
  background.width = docwidth;
  background.height = docheight;
  context.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height, 0, 0, docwidth, docheight);
};

function change_image_src(src) {
  image.src = $('#image-src').val();
}

// ... more image effect functions ...

function grayscale() {
  var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, background.width, background.height);
  var pixels = data.data;

  for (var x = 0; x < data.width; x++)
    for (var y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
      var i = (y * 4) * data.width + x * 4;
      var avg = (pixels[i] + pixels[i + 1] + pixels[i + 2]) / 3;
      pixels[i] = avg;
      pixels[i + 1] = avg;
      pixels[i + 2] = avg;
    }
  context.putImageData(data, 0, 0, 0, 0, data.width, data.height);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    // ... other cases ...
    case 71: // g
      grayscale();
      break;
  }
});
```

Btw, I do have *image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cross origin resource sharing is controlled by the **server** - any chrome _hacks_ to bypass such measures are **hacks** and potentially **dangerous**

Comment: How pointless would the same origin policy be if a website could grant itself permission to read data from another website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get over this problem using a CORS proxy server: http://crossorigin.me/

Answer (score 8):

In order to use images from another origin on a canvas without tainting it, the image must be **served** with CORS headers. [This page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) explains it, but essentially, when the image is served, it has to be accompanied by an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allowing the origin of your page (potentially via the `*` wildcard).

Unless the image is *served* that way, putting it in the canvas will taint it, and you won't be able to use `getImageData`.

So this isn't a JavaScript thing, really; it's how the image is *served* that determines how you can use it.

Comment: Exactly.  It takes participation of client __and__ server.  If you could use resources from other servers using only JS, that would eliminate the entire purpose of having a CORS policy.

Comment: is there an way with jsbin or any other html/css/js hosting server that allows me to serve the CORS headers?

Comment: @OfekGila: Again, it doesn't matter how you serve your HTML/CSS/JS. What matters is how the **image** is served. Your code seems to let people provide any image URL so you can greyscale it. That will only work if the image they provide is served with the CORS header. The only way around that would be if **you** have a server, send the URL to it, have it request the image, and then send the image to your page -- then, since it's coming from your origin, you can use it without tainting the canvas (or you can serve it with the header if you want your page hosted elsewhere). You need a server.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: alright, thanks so much. Does that bean that the webpage will work depending on the image?

Comment: @OfekGila: Yes. If the image is served with the CORS header, it won't taint the canvas.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, alright, so I made a github project page, http://the-ofek-foundation.github.io/Image-Editor/, and I wanted to know if it would be possible to work around the CORS header somehow using this website.

Thanks in advance!