# Html2canvs did not render cross-origin images

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am using html2canvas to get screenshots of my specific `div` in Shopify. Inside the `div`, there are some images which come from external servers (Cross origin images).

I have tried all options but I am not able to capture external images in my screenshots. Here's my code which I am using:

```
$('#right-custom-shoe-blk').html2canvas({
  logging:true,
  useCORS: true,
  proxy: "https://analyzer.com/customise/html2canvasproxy.php",
  allowTaint : true,
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    console.log(canvas);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
  }
});
```

I have also tried to add a proxy url to capture images in my screenshots but didn't get anything.

Here's console response:-
[image]

Please help me out if there is any way to capture cross-origin images or if there is any alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there. Just open the browser's Javascript console and attach the error that you see there. That will help in understanding what the exact issue might be.

Comment: Is access-control-allow-origin: * set on the images? See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32559136/2177147

Comment: @rypskar Thanks for your response. I have already add headers in page but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SankalpSharma Thanks for your response. I have add console response in question. Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh a screenshot of "Network" tab might also help. Also, are you loading the site via "http://localhost"? If so, try running your site on a local domain like `http://local-test.com`. To do that, just add an entry `local-test.com .   127.0.0.1` in your system's hosts file.